# UFCS: Resolving T::method

Tags: rust

Context: I'm trying to parametrize a function by another function, and get it statically resolved. At a glance, the `Fn` trait bound seem to match my need.

What I expected to be the "wrapper" seems fine (up to now), I'm however badly stuck at just designating the method I'd like to pass on:

```
fn binop<T,Op:Fn<(T,T),T>>(op: Op, a:T, b:T) -> T {
    // [...]
    op.call((a,b))
}

fn addx(a: f64, b: f64) -> f64 {
    binop(f64::add, a, b)
    //    ^~~~~~~~ error: unresolved name `f64::add`.
}

fn main() {
    addx(1.0, 2.0);
}
```

I've been looking for hints in the UFCS RFC, and "randomly" tried a bunch of designation variants (up to referencing `std::ops::Add::add` and hopping for some magic inference to do the job), but admitedly can't get it right. Any help about (/ pointers to) the resolution mechanism would be much appreciated..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fn` is the new unboxed closures stuff. There’s also just straight `fn(…) -> …`, the simple function type. This sort of thing (bearing in mind that `add` takes its arguments by reference, not by value):

```
fn binop<T>(op: fn(&T, &T) -> T, a: &T, b: &T) -> T {
    // [...]
    op(a, b)
}

fn addx(a: f64, b: f64) -> f64 {
    binop(Add::add, &a, &b)
}

fn main() {
    addx(1.0, 2.0);
}
```

Run this through rustc and you get this:

```
error: internal compiler error: unexpected failure
note: the compiler hit an unexpected failure path. this is a bug.
note: we would appreciate a bug report: http://doc.rust-lang.org/complement-bugreport.html
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace
task 'rustc' failed at 'assertion failed: `(left == right) && (right == left)` (left: `3`, right: `0`)', /home/chris/rust/src/librustc/middle/trans/callee.rs:528
```

… hmm, maybe not so good in this particular case. It’s probably something to do with the trait type inference, but I couldn’t say what.

Comment: ICE reported to the (I guess) similar issue https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18501

Comment: Fixed in [#18061](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18061), your example just work now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Fn*` traits are unboxed closures traits, and unboxed closures are in active development right now. Some conveniences like automatic conversion from functions to their instances do not work yet, though I believe as unboxed closures are going to replace current boxed ones, something like this will work in future.

There is another problem, however. UFCS [is not implemented](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16293) yet, and I think they aren't going to be implemented for 1.0, so you can't specify trait methods generically now. You have to use explicit closure construction, for example:

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures, unboxed_closure_sugar, overloaded_calls)]

fn binop<T, Op: Fn(T, T) -> T>(op: Op, a: T, b: T) -> T {
    // [...]
    op(a, b)
}

fn addx(a: f64, b: f64) -> f64 {
    binop(|&: a: f64, b: f64| a + b, a, b)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", addx(1.0, 2.0));
}
```

(try it [here](http://is.gd/31bl1H))

Comment: Thanks for the information. A few commits did land but the RFC as a whole is indeed not complete, I should have had a closer look at the accompagning github issue.. Sorry for that.